# While loop only displaying one row

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach, while-loop

I have an HTML form that allows the user to select from a list of employees. The variable is '$empfullname.' However, I also want them to be able to select an 'All' option and if selected it should take the first employee and run the PHP script, then take the next, and so on and so forth. However, the code I have right now if 'All' is selected just displays the first employee in the table and stops. Maybe I need a foreach in their as well? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
if ($empfullname == 'All') {
    $query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees order by empfullname asc";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
} else {
    print timecard_html($empfullname, $local_timestamp_in_week);
}

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print timecard_html(stripslashes("".$row['empfullname'].""), $local_timestamp_in_week);

}
```

Comment: Does timecard_html() exit?

Comment: @dale No, timecard_html does not exit(). Good thought though. Had to check :)

Comment: Try this query:  "select count(*) from ".$db_prefix."employees" and see how many records are being returned.

Comment: You should put your loop in the `if` statement to avoid warnings about `$result` being undefined, etc..

Comment: [Don't use mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/2008384)

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop isn't within the if statement, try:

```
if ($empfullname == 'All') {
    $query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees order by empfullname asc";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         print timecard_html(stripslashes("".$row['empfullname'].""),    $local_timestamp_in_week);
    }
} 

else {
    print timecard_html($empfullname, $local_timestamp_in_week);
}
```

Also, I wouldn't use the same variable as the Employee's Full Name to check if 'All' is selected ;).