# If-statement while loop stopping after first row

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have the following PHP script that takes the selected $empfullname from the user and prints 'timecard_html' based on the selection. I am trying to make it capable that if they select 'All' then the script prints out all of the employees in the list each in a separate timecard_html. Here is the php script:

```
if ($empfullname == 'All') {
    $query = "select empfullname from ".$db_prefix."employees";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $empfullname = ("".$row['empfullname']."");
        print timecard_html($empfullname, $local_timestamp_in_week);
        unset($empfullname);
    }
} else {
    print timecard_html($empfullname, $local_timestamp_in_week);

}
```

Also, here is timecard_html in case you need to see it:

```
function timecard_html($empfullname, $local_timestamp_in_week) {
    // Return html of employee's timecard.
    global $show_display_name, $one_week;

    // SQL search parameters for one work week.
    $begin_local_timestamp = work_week_begin($local_timestamp_in_week);
    $end_local_timestamp = $begin_local_timestamp + $one_week;

    // Define helper functions for printing timecard header, footer, and for printing every row.
    function print_header($tc) {
        // Print timecard html header.
        global $overtime_week_limit, $timecard_display_running_total;

        $overtime_col = $overtime_week_limit > 0 ? "\n    <th align=\"center\" class=\"ovt\" title=\"Overtime hours\">OT</th>" : '';
        $total_col = $timecard_display_running_total == "yes" ? "\n    <th align=\"center\" class=\"total\" title=\"Running total of regular work hours and overtime to date.\">Total</th>" : '';
        print <<<End_Of_HTML

<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">In/Out</th>
    <th align="center">Time</th>
    <th align="center">Date</th>
    <th align="center" class="hrs" title="Regular work hours.">Hrs</th>$overtime_col$total_col
    <th align="left" class="notes">Notes</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
End_Of_HTML;
    }

    function print_row($tc) {
        // Configuration variables.
        global $timefmt, $datefmt;
        global $overtime_week_limit, $timecard_list_punch_outs, $timecard_display_hours_minutes;
        global $timecard_hours_include_overtime, $timecard_display_running_total;
        static $print_count = 0;

        if (($tc->in_or_out == 1) || $timecard_list_punch_outs == 'yes') {
            $h_color  = htmlentities($tc->row['color']);
            $h_inout  = htmlentities($tc->row['inout']);

            $h_time = date($timefmt, $tc->start_time);
            $h_date = date($datefmt, $tc->start_time);

            if ($timecard_display_hours_minutes == "yes") {
                $h_hours = hrs_min((($timecard_hours_include_overtime == "yes") ? ($tc->hours + $tc->overtime) : $tc->hours));
                $h_overtime = hrs_min($tc->overtime);
                $h_total = hrs_min(($tc->week_hours + $tc->overtime_hours));
            }
            else {
                $h_hours = sprintf("%01.02f",(($timecard_hours_include_overtime == "yes") ? ($tc->hours + $tc->overtime) : $tc->hours));
                $h_overtime = sprintf("%01.02f",$tc->overtime);
                $h_total = sprintf("%01.02f",($tc->week_hours + $tc->overtime_hours));
            }

            $h_notes  = htmlentities($tc->row['notes']);

            if ($tc->in_or_out != 1) {
                // Don't display hours on "out" records.
                $h_hours = $h_overtime = $h_total = '';
            }

            $row_class = (++$print_count % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';
            $overtime_col = $overtime_week_limit > 0 ? "\n    <td align=\"right\" class=\"ovt\">$h_overtime</td>" : '';
            $total_col = $timecard_display_running_total == "yes" ? "\n    <td align=\"right\" class=\"total\">$h_total</td>" : '';
            print <<<End_Of_HTML

  <tr class="display_row $row_class">
    <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:$h_color">$h_inout</td>
    <td align="right">$h_time</td>
    <td align="right">$h_date</td>
    <td align="right" class="hrs">$h_hours</td>$overtime_col$total_col
    <td align="left" class="notes">$h_notes</td>
  </tr>
End_Of_HTML;
        }
    }

    function print_footer($tc) {
        global $timecard_display_running_total, $timecard_hours_include_overtime;
        global $timecard_display_hours_minutes, $overtime_week_limit;

        // Set flag to print paragraph of totals if they're not already obvious.
        $print_totals = ($timecard_display_running_total == "yes" || $timecard_hours_include_overtime != "yes") ? true : false;

        $h_total_hours = sprintf("%01.02f",($tc->week_hours+$tc->overtime_hours));
        $h_totals = ($print_totals) ? "\n<p>Total for week: ".hrs_min($tc->week_hours + $tc->overtime_hours)." ($h_total_hours hours)</p>" : '';

        $h_ovt_total_hours = sprintf("%01.02f",$tc->overtime_hours);
        $h_overtime_totals = ($print_totals && $tc->overtime_hours > 0) ? "\n<p>Total overtime: ".hrs_min($tc->overtime_hours)." ($h_ovt_total_hours hours)</p>" : '';

        $h_day_total_hours = sprintf("%01.02f",$tc->today_hours);
        $h_today_hours = ($tc->today_hours !== null) ? "<p>Total today: ".hrs_min($tc->today_hours)." ($h_day_total_hours hours)</p>" : '';

        if ($timecard_display_running_total != "yes") {
            // Print row of totals 
            $total_hours = $timecard_hours_include_overtime == "yes" ? ($tc->week_hours+$tc->overtime_hours) : $tc->week_hours;
            $h_hours = $timecard_display_hours_minutes == "yes" ? hrs_min($total_hours) : $h_total_hours;
            $overtime_col = $overtime_week_limit > 0 ? "\n    <td align=\"right\" class=\"ovt\">".($timecard_display_hours_minutes == "yes" ? hrs_min($tc->overtime_hours) : $h_ovt_total_hours)."</td>" : '';
            $total_col = $timecard_display_running_total == "yes" ? "\n    <td align=\"right\" class=\"total\">".($timecard_display_hours_minutes == "yes" ? hrs_min($tc->week_hours+$tc->overtime_hours) : $h_total_hours)."</td>" : '';
            print <<<End_Of_HTML
  <tr class="total_row">
    <td align="left"></td>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td align="right" class="hrs">$h_hours</td>$overtime_col$total_col
    <td align="left" class="notes"></td>
  </tr>
End_Of_HTML;
        }

        print <<<End_Of_HTML
  </tbody>
</table>
End_Of_HTML;
        if ($timecard_display_running_total == "yes" || $timecard_hours_include_overtime != "yes" || $h_today_hours) {
            // Add totals text if totals are not already displayed or if summing the hours column is confusing.
            print <<<End_Of_HTML

<div class="totals">
$h_today_hours$h_totals$h_overtime_totals
</div>

End_Of_HTML;
        }
    }
    // End of helper function definitions.

    // Print timecard page header.
    $h_name_header = htmlentities( ($show_display_name == 'yes' ? get_employee_name($empfullname) : $empfullname) );
    $begin_date = date('l F j, Y',$begin_local_timestamp);
    print <<<End_Of_HTML

<div id="punchclock" class="timecard">
<h2>Timecard</h2>
<h3>$h_name_header</h3>
<h4>Week beginning $begin_date</h4>
End_Of_HTML;

    // Print timecard.
    $tc = new Timecard($empfullname,$begin_local_timestamp, $end_local_timestamp);
    list($row_count, $total_hours, $overtime_hours, $today_hours) = $tc->walk(print_header, print_row, print_footer);
    if ($row_count <= 0) print error_msg("No records were found.");

    // Print timecard page footer.
    print <<<End_Of_HTML
</div> <!-- timecard -->

End_Of_HTML;
}
?>
```

As of right now if 'All' is selected it prints the results for the first employee in the table, but not any of the other ones. Also, if I just print `("".$row['empfullname']."")` it prints out all the employees. Do I maybe need to use a for each loop instead of a while loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to follow your code, but my guess is there's a problem in the nesting of your HTML. If you View Source, do you see tables for other employees?

Comment: BTW, why do you write `$empfullname = ("".$row['empfullname']."");` instead of simply `$empfullname = $row['empfullname'];`? What is the concatenation for?

Comment: Unrelated but important: this code is structured *really* badly. Nested functions (why? the only difference is worse readability), globals all around, HTML mixed with business logic, the HTML is obsolete... you might want to improve on it.

Comment: I'm having a deja vu. Nearly the same question: The exact same problem but different section of code posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838736/while-loop-only-displaying-one-row. Any relation?

Comment: This is some vintage HTML - the "align" attribute is long deprecated. Use CSS to change your layout. It is also some vintage PHP - `mysql_` functions are no longer supported. Use `mysqli_` functions instead. Don't forget to use prepared statements to protect yourself against MYSQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your are defining functions in your function. That will work the first time when you call your function, but the second time it will cause a fatal error as the function is already defined.

See a [simple example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ez22A1).

Moving the inner function declarations out of the main function should solve this specific problem.

You should also always enable error handling and displaying while developing. In this case you would have caught the problem inmediately.

Just put this at the top of the main script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```